# subset data based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My df looks like this:

```
dfin <- 

ID   DAY   SIZE
1     -5    10
1     -2    15
1      0    10
1      1    20
2      5    20
3      -5   2
3      -4   10
3      1    15
```

I want to subset `DAY` rows such that: if the `DAY` value of a subject has value 0 (baseline) in the `DAY` values then subset data DAY >= 0 for that subject. If the value for a subject starts with a negative number (and doesn't have 0 baseline), then subset from the closet negative `DAY` to the positive `DAY` for that subject. if the value of `DAY` for a subject starts with a positive number (no negative `DAY`), then keep all rows for that subject.

The output should be this:

```
dfout <- 

ID   DAY   SIZE
1      0    10
1      1    20
2      5    20
3      -4   10
3      1    15
```

I am using RStudio. preferred solution using data.table, if possible (option 1) or dplyr (option 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfin)[, 
        if(any(DAY==0)) .SD[DAY>=0]
        else if (DAY[1L] < 0) .SD[last(which(DAY < 0)):.N] 
        else .SD, 
    ID]
```

output:

```
   ID DAY SIZE
1:  1   0   10
2:  1   1   20
3:  2   5   20
4:  3  -4   10
5:  3   1   15
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dfin <- fread("ID   DAY   SIZE
1     -5    10
1     -2    15
1      0    10
1      1    20
2      5    20
3      -5   2
3      -4   10
3      1    15")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function incorporating all the conditions

```
func <- function(value) {
    if (any(value == 0))
        which(value >= 0)
    else if (any(value < 0))
      max(which(value < 0)) :  max(which(value > 0))
    else seq_along(value)
}
```

and apply it to each group

```
library(data.table)
df[setDT(df)[, .I[func(DAY)], by = ID]$V1,]

#   ID DAY SIZE
#1:  1   0   10
#2:  1   1   20
#3:  2   5   20
#4:  3  -4   10
#5:  3   1   15
```

And in `dplyr` we can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(func(DAY))

#     ID   DAY  SIZE
#   <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     0    10
#2     1     1    20
#3     2     5    20
#4     3    -4    10
#5     3     1    15
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DAY = 
c(-5L, -2L, 0L, 1L, 5L, -5L, -4L, 1L), SIZE = c(10L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 
20L, 2L, 10L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to subset `DAY` rows such that: if the `DAY` value of a subject has value 0 (baseline) in the `DAY` values then subset data DAY >= 0 for that subject. If the value for a subject starts with a negative number (and doesn't have 0 baseline), then subset from the closet negative `DAY` to the positive `DAY` for that subject. if the value of `DAY` for a subject starts with a positive number (no negative `DAY`), then keep all rows for that subject.

That is, we want to drop anything strictly before a certain DAY, equal to zero or the nearest negative DAY:

```
# find lower bound, if any
lbDT = dfin[.(ID = unique(ID), DAY = 0L), on=.(ID, DAY), roll=TRUE, nomatch=0, 
  .(ID, first_DAY = x.DAY)
]

# use an anti-join to drop observations before/below the lower bound
dfin[!lbDT, on=.(ID, DAY < first_DAY)]

   ID DAY SIZE lb
1:  1   0   10 -5
2:  1   1   20 -5
3:  2   5   20  5
4:  3  -4   10 -5
5:  3   1   15 -5
```